# Lua-Pattern - Evaluate conditional expression

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I want to evaluate a conditional expression string, I defined following BNF:

```
X     ::= <value>    
COND  ::= X | X '==' X | '!{' COND '}' | '{' COND '&&' COND '}' | '{' COND '||' COND '}'
```

Based on this structur I wrote this evaluating-function, returning a boolean value:

```
-- Bedingung auswerten
  function eval(exp, valueTab, loopValue)
  -- !{COND} - Negierung
    if string.find(exp, '^!{(.+)}$') then
      return not eval(string.gsub(exp, '^!{(.+)}$', '%1'))
  -- {COND&&COND} - AND
    elseif string.find(exp, '^{(.+)&&(.+)}$') then
      return (eval(string.gsub(exp, '^{(.+)&&(.+)}$', '%1')) and eval(string.gsub(exp, '^{(.+)&&(.+)}$', '%2')))
  -- {COND||COND} - OR
    elseif string.find(exp, '^{(.+)||(.+)}$') then
      return (eval(string.gsub(exp, '^{(.+)||(.+)}$', '%1')) or eval(string.gsub(exp, '^{(.+)||(.+)}$', '%2')))
  -- X==X - Gleichheit -> true/false
    elseif string.find(exp, '^(.+)==(.+)$') then
      return (getValue(string.gsub(exp, '^(.+)==(.+)$', '%1'), valueTab, loopValue) == getValue(string.gsub(exp, '^(.+)==(.+)$', '%2'), valueTab, loopValue))
  -- X -> false wenn X nil/false auswertet ansonsten true
    else
      return (getValue(exp, valueTab, loopValue) and true or false)
    end
  end
```

But it's not working for some nested conditions like

```
exp = '{{1||boolean:false}&&{boolean:true&&!{boolean:false}}}'
```

The first recursive step splits the expression into

```
eval('{1||boolean:false}&&{boolean:true') and
eval('!{boolean:false}}'
```

Any idea how I can check, if the number of '{' is equal to the number of '}'? It should split the expression like

```
eval('{1||boolean:false}') and
eval('{boolean:true&&!{boolean:false}}')
```

I hope u understand my question, if u have any further questions let me know.
I'm also willing to change my syntax, if u have a better idea. But negation, AND- and OR-Clauses should be supported.

Comment: Parsing expressions requires a proper parser. But try the pattern `%b{}`, which matches balanced `{}`.

Comment: `'^{(!?%b{})&&(!?%b{})}$'` looks pretty good, but i doesnt fetch the values. any idea how to get them without editing the BNF grammar? (for instance to `'!'? '{' X }'` and `'!'? '{'X '==' X'}'`)

Comment: Anyway, thanks for this tip. I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

> Parsing expressions requires a proper parser. But try the pattern `%b{}`, which matches balanced `{}`.

I did it this way:

1. Editing the BNF

   ```
   COND  ::= '{' (X|X '==' X|COND '&&' COND|COND '||' COND) '}'|'!' COND
   ```
2. Editing pattern

   ```
   -- Bedingung auswerten
     function eval(exp, valueTab, loopValue)
     -- !{COND} - Negierung
       if string.find(exp, '^!(%b{})$') then
         return not eval(string.gsub(exp, '^!(%b{})$', '%1'))
     -- {COND&&COND} - AND
       elseif string.find(exp, '^{(!?%b{})&&(!?%b{})}$') then
         return (eval(string.gsub(exp, '^{(!?%b{})&&(!?%b{})}$', '%1')) and eval(string.gsub(exp, '^{(!?%b{})&&(!?%b{})}$', '%2')))
     -- {COND||COND} - OR
       elseif string.find(exp, '^{(!?%b{})||(!?%b{})}$') then
         return (eval(string.gsub(exp, '^{(!?%b{})||(!?%b{})}$', '%1')) or eval(string.gsub(exp, '^{(!?%b{})||(!?%b{})}$', '%2')))
     -- X==X - Gleichheit -> true/false
       elseif string.find(exp, '^{(.+)==(.+)}$') then
         return (getValue(string.gsub(exp, '^{(.+)==(.+)}$', '%1'), valueTab, loopValue) == getValue(string.gsub(exp, '^{(.+)==(.+)}$', '%2'), valueTab, loopValue))
     -- X -> false wenn X nil/false auswertet ansonsten true
       elseif string.find(exp, '^{(.+)}$') then
         return (getValue(string.gsub(exp, '^{(.+)}$', '%1'), valueTab, loopValue) and true or false)
       else
         print('wrong syntax')
         return
       end
     end
   ```

Answer (score 3):

The grammar is pretty simple and [LPEG](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/lpeg.html) allows you to basically copy the grammar almost verbatim, sprinkle it with some semantic actions and it just works™.

If you want to learn more about LPEG and parsing expression grammars, I recommend this tutorial: http://leafo.net/guides/parsing-expression-grammars.html

```
local lpeg = require"lpeg"
local P, V = lpeg.P, lpeg.V

local True = function() return true end
local False = function() return false end
local Not = function(a) return not a end
local Eq = function(a,b) return a == b end
local And = function(a,b) return a and b end
local Or = function(a,b) return a or b end

local grammar = P{
    "cond",
    cond = (V"x")
         + (V"x" * "==" * V"x") / Eq
         + (P"!{" * V"cond" * P"}") / Not
         + (P"{" * V"cond" * P"&&" * V"cond" * P"}") / And
         + (P"{" * V"cond" * P"||" * V"cond" * P"}") / Or,
    x = P"1" / True
      + P"0" / False
      + P"boolean:true" / True
      + P"boolean:false" / False
}

local eval = function(exp)
    return grammar:match(exp)
end

print(eval('{{1||boolean:false}&&{boolean:true&&!{boolean:false}}}'))
```